# Outside outlet not working

Tags: wiring, repair, walls, deck, cord-and-plug

Yesterday I was outside to do lawn weed eater to cut the grasses around the garden. So I had to plug it into the outlet at the top and bottom. It doesn't work at all.

So, this morning I tried on one of these at a another place and different outlet. It was working. What might cause this jackwall not working?

[image: Backyard jackwall]

I had a mouse trap equipment that is plugged earlier. I did smell something burned.. I have plugged in and check for the light to come on or not. It did not.

Your thoughts for me to get it fixed?

P.S. I am adding this electronic panel ...[image: electronic panel]

Comment: Are all the nonfunctional receptacles on the same circuit, or are they on different circuits?

Comment: I am not familiar with it .

Comment: Check your circuit breaker panel, look for a breaker that has tripped - the handle should be in the middle position, neither off nor on, often with a red/orange indicator showing. If you're not sure, take a picture and [edit] it into your question. Does the "mouse trap equipment" work if you plug it into a different outlet?

Comment: Get a plug-in circuit tester and see what it tells you when you plug it in. Don't assume that this receptacle is not hot --it may be hot. The problem may be in the neutral. If it is not a simple case of a tripped breaker, the problem could be in this box or in one upstream. Do you know if this receptacle is the only one on its breaker or are there other receptacles on the same breaker?

Comment: Also in troubleshooting, look for a gfci outlet that's tripped. It might be nearby; it might be in the garage; it might even be in a bathroom.

Comment: The bad news is that it's not a simple tripped breaker...